# Duplicate WiFi tag on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are two tags which are synonymous to each-other and they have the same description: [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi) and [wi-fi](/questions/tagged/wi-fi). The `wifi` tag is used more often than `wi-fi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea, I've merged and synonymized them so in the future this won't happen again.